# How to test if an object is a Stream in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I have a function which receives an object that could be a `string`, `Buffer` or `Stream`.

I can easily test if the object is a Buffer like so:
`if (x instanceof Buffer)`

What's the best way to test if an object is a Stream? There doesn't appear to be a Stream base class in node - is there?

What should I look for?

Comment: Another way to test if an object is a Buffer is `Buffer.isBuffer(x)` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858138/whats-the-use-of-buffer-isbuffer-when-you-could-use-instanceof))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The prototype you are looking for is the `stream.Readable` stream for readable streams, and `stream.Writable` for writable streams. They work in the same way as when you check for `Buffer`.

Comment: should this be lower case stream.readable? it does not seem to have the property with upper case

Comment: Thanks Sebastien, please add some code next time. I am a noob and can't parse how to compare this answer to the next one.

Answer (score 13):

For `Readable` you can do:

```
var stream = require('stream');

function isReadableStream(obj) {
  return obj instanceof stream.Stream &&
    typeof (obj._read === 'function') &&
    typeof (obj._readableState === 'object');
}

console.log(isReadableStream(fs.createReadStream('car.jpg'))); // true
console.log(isReadableStream({}))); // false
console.log(isReadableStream(''))); // false
```

Comment: thx for giving reproducible code, used it in https://github.com/loveencounterflow/hollerith tests

Answer (score 10):

Not all streams are implemented using `stream.Readable` and `stream.Writable`.

```
process.stdout instanceof require("stream").Writable; // false
process.stdout instanceof require("readable-stream").Writable; // false
```

The better method is to individually check for the `read(), write(), end()` functions.

```
var EventEmitter = require("events");

function isReadableStream(test) {
    return test instanceof EventEmitter && typeof test.read === 'function'
}

function isWritableStream(test) {
    return test instanceof EventEmitter && typeof test.write === 'function' && typeof test.end === 'function'
}
```

You can always reffer to: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/node/node.d.ts#L252

Comment: is it safe to assume that this code ( `process.stdout instanceof require("stream").Writable;` ) is the best way to assume that a stream is a `process.stdout`?

Comment: @hisabimbola No simply use `instanceof require("events").EventEmitter` and check for the `write` and `end` properties. Anything else will fail at one  point or another.

Comment: What I am trying to do is test that a writable stream is exactly `process.stdout` not test if it's a writable stream. More info about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41521709/4151025)

Comment: @hisabimbola You'll have to manually check if the stream is a terminal (`instanceof require("tty").WriteStream === true`). Then check its handle to make sure its either `stdin` or `stdout` (`test._handle.fd < 0`).

Comment: According to the documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/tty.html), this (`node -p -e "Boolean(process.stdout.isTTY)" | cat`) outputs `false`, because it's not TTY though it's `process.stdout`

Comment: @hisabimbola follow instructions node -p -e "process.stdout instanceof require('tty').WriteStream". There you go. I'm not sure about handles though. You will have to check the source code from node `1.10` up to latest. Once you have confirmed if it is a terminal then just check to make sure its handle is connected to `stdout`.