# What's the use of 'Buffer.isBuffer' when you could use 'instanceof'?

Tags: node.js

I don't understand what is the purpose of the `Buffer.isBuffer` function when `instanceof` works like a charm :

```
var b = new Buffer('blabla')
assert.ok(b instanceof Buffer)
```

Comment: `instanceof` is often frowned upon. Read [this](http://perfectionkills.com/instanceof-considered-harmful-or-how-to-write-a-robust-isarray/). I'm not sure it's not overprotective in the case of node.

Comment: `Buffer.isBuffer()` appears to have been [introduced by Ryan Dahl](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/02729d4af7b17ea4c7272a0d0d99f6f7418e3237). The commit doesn't explain why, but it's probably just a matter of refactoring and having one common definition for determining what's a "*buffer*." This makes it easier to maintain and possibly change if ever needed. Though, yes, it's currently just `instance Buffer`.

Comment: `isBuffer` is deprecated at the moment.

Comment: @DenysSéguret But that article's about arrays in multi iframe DOM environment. That's about as far away from node.js as you can get (and node.js is what this question is about).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Well, actually these are the same (currently at least):

[**-- lib/buffer.js**](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/8874a317484b8865c5fbad74d3af6155994df583/lib/buffer.js#L121):

```
Buffer.isBuffer = function isBuffer(b) {
  return util.isBuffer(b);
};
```

[**-- lib/util.js**](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/8874a317484b8865c5fbad74d3af6155994df583/lib/util.js#L584):

```
function isBuffer(arg) {
  return arg instanceof Buffer;
}
exports.isBuffer = isBuffer;
```

... so the only possible reason is readability. Note that before this specific implementation there was a [set of macros](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/9a29aa8c552eb2b120c101c1cfd66ba565a17ed5/src/macros.py) for type checks, used when building the source. But it has been changed with [this commit](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/22c68fdc1dae40f0ed9c71a02f66e5b2c6353691), and that was the reasoning:

> Adding macros to Node's JS layer increases the barrier to
>   contributions, and it breaks programs that export Node's js files for
>   userland modules. (For example, several browserify transforms, my
>   readable-streams polyfill, the util-debuglog module, etc.) These are
>   not small problems.

I'd suggest checking the whole discussion in the commit's [**pull request**](https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/5938).