# Why do we need Buffer.isBuffer method?

Tags: node.js, buffer

Why do we need  `Buffer.isBuffer` method when we know it's doing the same thing as `instanceof Buffer` ?

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/buffer.js#L306

Comment: This would be useful to you,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858138/whats-the-use-of-buffer-isbuffer-when-you-could-use-instanceof

Comment: thanks! it's the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not technically necessary. It exists for convenience and is probably, to at least a degree, idiomatic.

No extended explanation was given [when it was defined](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/commit/02729d4af7b17ea4c7272a0d0d99f6f7418e3237), but it appears to have been a refactoring ([DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) – answer "*what is a buffer*" once and reuse) and/or a stylistic preference:

```
-  if (!(buffer instanceof Buffer)) {
+  if (!Buffer.isBuffer(buffer)) {
```

There was probably some inspiration taken from [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray).

And, it does also offer some additional backwards compatibility (or possibly some future-proofing), as not all of Node's versions [have had a single type for Buffers](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/blob/v0.4/lib/buffer.js#L214-L217):

```
Buffer.isBuffer = function isBuffer(b) {
  return b instanceof Buffer || b instanceof SlowBuffer;
};
```