# Check if a stream is process.stdout

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-stream

Is there an elegant way to determine if a stream is `process.stdout`

I am working with streams and will like to end the stream, but found out that if the stream is `process.stdout` an error is thrown because `process.stdout` is a special stream that [cannot be closed](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout). So want to end all streams except it's `process.stdout`

I tried using a try and catch, but the `process.stdout` error ends the node process, ignoring the try and catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is naive of me, but I'd think you can just check with `!==`:

```
if (theStream !== process.stdout) {
    theStream.end();
}
```

Streams are objects, and there's only one `process.stdout`, so...

Comment: I personally think a try/catch block, which eats the exception, is quite possibly the best way to do it - obviously rethrowing the error if it is not the exact one you expect :)

Comment: @Barnabus: I just read the last sentence in the question (which I'd somehow missed), where the OP suggests doing that blows up the process. (Which seems very surprising.)

Comment: @Barnabus: ***Wow***, and I've just verified that with Node v4 and Node v7.

Comment: That is suprising. Especially considering the docs mention that calling `end()` throws! You would have thought the error would be catchable

Comment: @Barnabus: You can indeed catch that exception. But then the next time you try to write to `process.stdout` (for instance, via `console.log`), it throws with `Error: write after end`.

Comment: Another method I found was this "process.stdout instanceof require('stream').Writable" will return false, but true for other types of streams. Not sure how far it will work though